# Need to get particular string output from a given string using C#

Tags: c#

I have a string like below.

```
Window("text:=E2E testing system 9304E-EX Pack (t103/35)").KCMLList("module_list..list").Select "Purchase ledger"
```

what I want is to get the Window part only that is upto below portion.

```
"Window("text:=E2E testing system 9304E-EX Pack (t103/35)")"
```

Please note the value inside the brace can be anything (including special character). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look into Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can start scanning along after "Window(" until you reach a ')' character. There are a few complications you need to hold state for. For example when you hit a '"' character you need to set an InString state to true, which you only disable upon encountering another '"' character. Once you reach a ')' character when the state is not in a string you have reached the last position. There is a bunch of other stuff you might have to check for such as escape characters. This problem is not solvable using regular expressions (or at least it shouldn't be).

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate a little more. If I start from "Window(" till I reach ")", I won't be getting the right brace for window since there is a possibility of having another matching brace inside window section. I tried finding matching braces using stack object but didn't work out for me. If you could elaborate a little more would be immensely helpful for me. Thanks in advance.